# I read that Monero is a Bytecoin fork. When launched in 2014, how was Monero's software different?

Tags: history, bytecoin

I know it didn't have a premine, unlike Bytecoin, but was its software any different as well?

Edit: I've read the history between the two, but the details on their original software differences isn't described there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the origin of Monero and its relationship to Bytecoin?](http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/852/what-is-the-origin-of-monero-and-its-relationship-to-bytecoin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that it is/was a fork of Bytecoin, Monero inherited (almost) all of its code/software. That is, there were a couple of small changes (e.g. different block time and emission schedule if I recall correctly), but almost all of the code was similar to that of Bytecoin. Over the years Monero has largely deviated from the Bytecoin (and CryptoNote) code. The progression can be read in the [2014](https://getmonero.org/2015/01/05/monero-missive-2014-year-in-review.html) and [2015](https://getmonero.org/2016/02/10/monero-missive-2015-year-in-review.html) year in review.