# Where and when was Monero started?

Tags: history

I'd like to know where and when was Monero started please.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [collection of StackExchange posts talking about the history](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history):.

This one is of particular interest: [What is the origin of Monero and its relationship to Bytecoin?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/852/what-is-the-origin-of-monero-and-its-relationship-to-bytecoin)

See also a nice collection of history-related posts found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/6ud6wh/the_strange_birth_history_of_monero_4_part_series/).

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monero_(cryptocurrency)#History

You can also look at different price chart websites to see what the prices have been in the past, such as https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/monero/