# Is there information available about the Levin protocol?

Tags: monerod, cryptography, p2p, source-code-documentation

Is there any information available about the [Levin protocol](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/2846d0850d6e92d38c44eac9e6a4fca6b1545453/contrib/epee/include/net/levin_protocol_handler_async.h)?
It seems to be used for the peer to peer communication.

Things like:

1. The working of the protocol?
2. What are the benefits? Why was it chosen for Monero?
3. Is it used in any other product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also [see here for their repo docs](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/docs/LEVIN_PROTOCOL.md).

Answer (score 6):

I did find the following information:

- Some information about the history you can find [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/475/monero-inception-and-history-how-did-monero-get-started-what-are-its-origins-a/477#477).
- It is part of the so called 'epee' library.
- The creator is a Russian programmer called Andrey N. Sabelnikov, who seems to be well known for creating a botnet.
- The original code is located on [Github](https://github.com/sabelnikov/epee).
- It doesn't seem to be used anywhere else besides some cryptocurrencies with a similar background as Monero.
- On the site of the [Boolberry](http://boolberry.org/design.html) cryptocurrency you can find some design information.