# Does monero p2p protocol use magic bytes?

Tags: network, protocol, p2p

Bitcoin (and derived altcoins) use magic byte prefixes to identify their network messages and to distinguish between clients running on different networks/chains such as testnet or an altcoin.  Does Monero use something similar?   If so, what is the value, and where is the code that defines it?

In bitcoin, the value is 0xd9b4bef9 and it is defined at:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.16.1/src/chainparams.cpp#L115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monero uses the Levin protocol for p2p comms. 
Similar question [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2615/is-there-information-available-about-the-levin-protocol).

The definitions for the commands are [here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/p2p/p2p_protocol_defs.h).